# global array values can't be accessed inside for loop

Tags: javascript

why is it my global array values cannot be used inside a for loop
providing:

```
testing = [];


for (var x=0; x<10; x++){
    console.log(testing); 
}
```

**the "testing" variable is dynamically filled with array**

- this for loop code above, it will have an error like this,https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBjH2.png

---

*this is how it looks like with* console.log(testing); *w/o for loop
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKhqA.png

**this is the function that fills the array**

```
     function showMyVideos(data)
    {
        var feed = data.feed;
        var entries = feed.entry || [];
         for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)
        {
            var entry = entries[i];
            var vid = (getVideoId(entry.link[0].href));
            testing[i] = vid;
        }       
  console.log(testing)
    }
```

this is how it looks like if I console.log inside this function

http*//goo.gl/nVfQn

*replace (asterisk)  with (colon) to see the link

> why is it, it only works within the function scope while I have this declared it globally

Comment: What? If you have an empty array, it won't fill itself. Not sure what you're expecting.

Comment: You need to post the code that puts values in the array.

Comment: ok, I edited and added the function

Comment: OK great.  Now, what does "getVideoId()" do?  (My guess: it makes an asynchronous call to a server ...)

Comment: @Pointy yup, to an api.

function getVideoId(url)
  {    
    return url.substring(url.indexOf("=")+1,url.lastIndexOf("&"));
  }

Comment: why is it, it only works within the function scope while I have this declared globally.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error.  That's showing you an empty array in your console which is exactly what your `testing` was declared as.

Chances are you're not getting any entries and it's initializing to empty string.

```
 var entries = feed.entry || [];
```

Then when you try to loop `entries.length == 0`

Try to do a `console.log(entries.length);` before your loop.

Try this:

```
 testing = ["foo"];


for (var x=0; x<10; x++){
    console.log(testing);  
 }
```

You should see in your console something like:

```
 >["foo"]
 >["foo"]
 >["foo"]
  ...and so on
```

Comment: what's with the number referring on my screenshot?

Comment: @MarkBean the little circled number means that the message has been logged that many times in a row.

Comment: but it works on the function scope.

Comment: @MarkBean If feed.entry == 0 or false you're assigning entries = [] soe entries.length would be 0

Comment: but it returns true and has values. I had it run on console and on that scope function only