# Global array values losses data outside function scope

Tags: javascript

Why is it, it only works within the function scope while I have this declared it globally

```
testing = [];

function func1(){
  //some codes here that fills the "testing" array... 
}
//I want to display here the new array values..
```

watch it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24Ffs/6/)

1. click on the button
2. inspect element the output,
3. on the console

> I need the "testing" array on another function. how will I use it
>   then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [global array values can't be accessed inside for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635303/global-array-values-cant-be-accessed-inside-for-loop)

Comment: @Pointy It's not a duplicate, that guy had an empty array he didn't fill. This guy filled his array asynchronously and tried to access it before it was filled.

Comment: Your testing array is accessible to other functions. The reason nothing is printed in the "outside function scope" log is because it is empty at that point

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Except they are the same guy, and it looks suspiciously like the same code sample (and they were asked less than an hour apart).

Comment: @mellamokb oh lol, I wasn't aware of that ^_^ my bad. It's still a different question though.

Comment: Call your "other function" at the end of "showMyVideos()".  That's the point at which the array will be populated; it doesn't happen instantaneously because the content has to be fetched from another server.

Answer (score 1):

Your array gets populated **after** this `console.log("outside function scope :\n"+testing);` gets called.

Ignoring all the problems in your jsfiddle, the reason you're not seeing the behavior you expect is because the event that causes the array to be populated is asynchronous where the code that displays it outside the scope gets executed right away.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the order in which the messages appear in the console.  When page loads:

```
outside function scope :
```

After clicking the button:

```
inside function scope :
RSdKmX2BH7o,EWMLMc3ES3I,SIXwlxhjaKY,RIKTFn5ALE8,acp8TbBPVos,6GpKR4-TLoI,XLKLkTnKRwg,6WPELkw5kD0
```

The code outside of any function scope runs immediately as soon as the page is loaded, but the code that is populating `testing` only runs after clicking the button.

Comment: can you suggest a possible solution? I also thought of that and have tried to assign the "Testing" variable to a new varible that is also global. but same results.

Comment: What do you need to do with the results?  Just do it after they've been loaded.

Comment: I need the array data to a different function.. can you help with this? http://jsfiddle.net/aKX87/3/

I am trying to dynamic result from this static one -- > http://jsfiddle.net/9zqL6/3/